# Ubuntu to install jdk1.6

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, java-6

I was trying to install jdk1.6 onto my Ubuntu 10.04.

However, It looks like jdk1.6 is no longer available in Ubuntu repository(at least, i havent found it yet).

In my case, I need to install jdk1.6 as my java version instead of openjdk.

Could anyone tell me if it still could be found in anywhere?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest installing it manually. Use the following link and use update-alternatives. The instructions are for 1.7 but they work for 1.6. Just get it from sun's site.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7

Answer (score 0):

You can download JDK from java.sun.com and install it yourself.  The reason its not included because it needs you to accept their license agreement.

HTH.